# Find current location using Google Maps API in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have been trying to use Google Maps API in one of my projects and the problem is it's not showing me the current **exact location** even after allowing the location access (it's a Website Project). I mean it's outputting the location but like 200 metres away. When I try to use Google Maps' web version on the same device it's showing me the current location +-20 metres. We are trying to find the exact longitude and latitude. Here is the **JavaScript**

```
function getCurrentLocation() {
    var  options = {
        enableHighAccuracy: true,
        timeout: 5000,
        maximumAge: 0
    }
}
// Try HTML5 geolocation.
if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
        var pos = {
            lat: position.coords.latitude,
            lng: position.coords.longitude
        };
        var lat_and_long = pos.lat+","+pos.lng;
        $("#geocomplete").geocomplete("find", lat_and_long);
    }
}

$("#geocomplete").bind("geocode:dragged", function(event, latLng){
    $("input[name=lat]").val(pos.lat());
    $("input[name=lng]").val(pos.lng());
    $("#reset").show();
    console.log(latLng);
});
console.log(pos);

function handleLocationError(browserHasGeolocation, infoWindow, pos) {
        infoWindow.setPosition(pos);
        infoWindow.setContent(browserHasGeolocation ?
            'Error: The Geolocation service failed.' :
            'Error: Your browser doesn\'t support geolocation.');
        infoWindow.open(map);
}
```

We are using the following Google API with jQuery Geocoding and Places Autocomplete Plugin (1.7.0)
`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places&key=AIzaSyDJ2bLO-XXXXXXX"`

Comment: Google Maps (if you are logged in) has a more accurate position for you than can be acquired from HTML5 geolocation.

Comment: I don't think you can use the `geocomplete` **jQuery** plugin to search for a location using coordinates, I think the `find` method only works with addresses.

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply. I used a new phone and tried to search the exact location in incognito mode ( safari browser)  through google maps its showing the exact location, But as I tried to use the get current location in my web project it again showed me 100-200 metres away. @geocodezip

Comment: Do you know any library or code that will give me close to exact loaction in the samw way I have been getting through using google maps website @Titus

Comment: Was the phone using HTML5 geolocation or GPS?  (My suspicion is it is using HTML5 geolocation, which would have the same accuracy as a desktop using HTML5 geolocation)

Comment: Hi we are using both of them on the browser so HTML5 more on this video https://drive.google.com/file/d/1x8rPE9AqF-Qxt1ojlaE83Xi5QS64mff8/view

Comment: Hi. I tried your code (minus the jquery geocomplete code) and logged the lat and lng points to the console and I then checked these points on https://www.gps-coordinates.net/ and they are returning my exact address. I am on desktop browser currently. Maybe you could try your code firstly without the jquery geocode and check the lat and lng points on https://www.gps-coordinates.net/?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Google maps API gives locations based on below sources :

1. **GPS**: Gives you location by using satellites  (up to around 20 meters) sometimes its inaccurate like bad weather conditions, underground or if you are you're inside buildings.
2. **Wi-Fi**: The location of  Wi-Fi networks IP address.
3. **Cell tower**: Your connection to a mobile cellular network tower can be accurate up to a few thousand meters.

**DESKTOP BROWSER :** while browse through desktop browsers like Mozilla Firefox and Google Chrome location rely on local network information, signals such as your computer's `IP address`. 
your browsers will ask you to share your location, if you allow to share then information about nearby wireless access points and  `IP address` will share to Google Location Services to get an estimate of your location.
The accuracy of location  will vary by location.

**MOBILE BROWSER :**  Mobile browsers like Chrome,Safari,Opera use `GPS sensors` rather than WiFi network.

now `enableHighAccuracy` option attribute provides a hint that the application would like to receive the best possible results. 
This MAY result in slower response times or increased power consumption.

according to W3C's Geolocation API doc (https://w3c.github.io/geolocation-api/#high-accuracy) `No guarantee is given that the API returns the device's actual location`.

> The Geolocation API defines a high-level interface to location
>   information associated only with the device hosting the
>   implementation, such as latitude and longitude. The API itself is
>   agnostic of the underlying location information sources. Common
>   sources of location information include Global Positioning System
>   (GPS) and location inferred from network signals such as IP address,
>   RFID, WiFi and Bluetooth MAC addresses, and GSM/CDMA cell IDs, as well
>   as user input. No guarantee is given that the API returns the device's
>   actual location.

Comment: My question is if you goto maps.google.com and click how it is showing almost exact location?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to get the exact location. Each location method contains errors. GPS is the most accurate, but the error is still in several meters range.

---

In JavaScript, your best option is to use

```
if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
        var pos = {
            lat: position.coords.latitude,
            lng: position.coords.longitude
        };
        // ...
    } 
}
```

---

The `Coordinates.accuracy` read-only property is a strictly positive double representing the accuracy, with a 95% confidence level, of the `Coordinates.latitude` and `Coordinates.longitude` properties expressed in meters.

See details [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Coordinates/accuracy).